# Loopback Applications Functions Errors

Tags: mysql, loopbackjs

I am developing vuejs applications by using loopback and mysql . when i run the applications I got errors is 
**app.start is not functions** .

here is my code server.js ..

```
// Copyright IBM Corp. 2016. All Rights Reserved.
// Node module: loopback-workspace
// This file is licensed under the MIT License.
// License text available at https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

'use strict';

var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

module.exports = function(app) {
  // Install a "/ping" route that returns "pong"
  app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    res.send('pong');
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

Here is my route.js file code

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var router = app.loopback.Router();
  router.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
    res.send('pongaroo');
  });
  app.use(router);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the server.js file should contain a function called app.start. In this function only the server get started. In the server.js file try to add app.start(), hope that will solve your issue. Refer below pease of code for the app.start function.

```
    app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};
```